# Applying a function to a muti-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to apply an operation to the following data frame:

```
index   date        username    count
0       2015-11-01  1           16
1       2015-11-01  2           1
2       2015-11-01  3           1
3       2015-10-01  1           2
4       2015-10-01  4           29
5       2015-10-01  5           1
6       2014-09-01  1           3
7       2014-09-01  3           1
8       2014-09-01  4           1
```

And apply an operation that will get it to this:

```
index   date        mean
0       2015-11-01  6
1       2015-10-01  10.7
2       2014-09-01  1.3
```

The calculation takes the sum of all counts in a given date (e.g. for 2015-11-01 is it is 16+1+1=18) then divides by the unique number of usernames for a given date (e.g. for 2015-10-01 there are 3). A new column, mean is created to record the calculation, in this case we have called it mean.

I have been trying to use the 'apply' method from DataFrame but without success yet. Help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GroupBy` + `sum` divided by `GroupBy` + `nunique`:

```
g = df.groupby('date')
res = g['count'].sum().div(g['username'].nunique())\
                .rename('mean').reset_index()

print(res)

         date       mean
0  2014-09-01   1.666667
1  2015-10-01  10.666667
2  2015-11-01   6.000000
```

Comment: I think OP wants sum of `count` col divided by number of unique usernames per group.

Comment: @Abhi, Yes, that's the definition of `mean` by group.

Comment: No I'm not taking about mean. This code may fail if number of unique usernames is less. I mean for first three rows if usernames are `[1,1,2]` then OP wants to divide it by only 2 because unique count is 2.